# Not able to work out Threads,Handler and Sending SMS in android

Tags: android, multithreading, sms, handler

I am running a Thread which is displaying 30seconds in a textView.EG:30,29,28,27...so on till 0sec..
So when it reaches 0 seconds ,a message is sent to a defined number with a defined message.

My problem is that even if i stop the thread in between and it shows that it has stopped ;still the method **sendTextMessageAlert();** somehow is called and SMS is sent..
Following things m doing in my coding:

```
 uiPost = new Handler();
        running = true;
        timerThread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            int i;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for( i=30;i>=0;i--)
                {
                    if(running)
                    {
                          uiPost.post(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                setTimerText(i);
                            }
                        });
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }else
                    {
                        timerThread.stop();

                        end();
                        //Intent iii=new Intent(Alert.this,FearAlert.class);
                        //startActivity(iii);
                    }
                }

            }//run end
        });
        timerThread.start();



        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //timerThread.stop();
                running=false;
                 // endAlert();
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "By Button,Monitoring Stopped", 0).show();

            }
        });
}   
public void end(){
    vibrator.cancel();
    this.locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    if(wakeLock.isHeld())
        wakeLock.release();

    finish();
}
     private void setTimerText(int i)
  {

     ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView03)).setText(String.valueOf(i) + "s");

        if(i==0)
        {
            running=false;
            sendTextMessageAlert();
            vibrator.cancel();
            this.locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            if(wakeLock.isHeld())
                wakeLock.release();
            finish();

        }


  }



private void sendTextMessageAlert() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SendSMS task=new SendSMS(); 
    task.startSMS();
}

class SendSMS 
{
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("FearAlert", 1);
    String contactNumber1 = myPrefs.getString("contactNumber1", number);

public void startSMS() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(contactNumber1,
             null, 
        getSharedPreferences("FearAlert", 1).getString("message",getString( R.string.default_emergency_message)+sss), 
        null, null);        
}
```

M using **boolean running** for checking and stopping the thread.Please help me,why still **sendTextMessageAlert** is been called when i pressed the **Button B1**?
Any Solutions..
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Thread use `CountDownTimer` to perform this task as because `stop()` method of `Thread` is deprecated and you should not stop a thread.

```
android.os.CountDownTimer.CountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)
```

`CountDownTimer` also have `cancel()` method to cancel timer

It also have methods like `public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)` and `public void onFinish()` which will be helpful for you to perform your tasks whatever you want